# Is there a way to see which git commands Pycharm is running?

Tags: git, pycharm

I have been using git via Pycharm GUI, but recently I started doing some practice in using git from command line.
For some git actions I performed via Pycharm GUI, I would like to know the equivalent git lines of code.

Is there a way to see which git commands Pycharm have run?

To be clear, I would need something similar to the system that allows MS Excel to record macros,
tracking down the lines of code that correspond to the actions performed via UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>9</kbd> would give you the git window for Pycharm ([docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2021.2/version-control-tool-window-console-tab.html)). When you create commits (or do other actions that require commands from git) you would see a `Console` window and there are the commands that are executed by Pycharm.

[image]

You can expand the commands that Pycharm uses by pressing on the borders after the `git` command, like so `git -c ...` (this would expand to the full command).

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!!